# Short to Char Casting

Tags: c, arrays, casting, char, short

I have seen this done both ways. Is there any advantages or disadvantages to doing it either way?

```
short x = 0x9D6C;
char cx[2];

First way:
cx[0] = x &0xff;
cx[1] = (x >> 8) & 0xff;
```

vs.
Second way:

```
memcpy(cx, (char*)&x, 2);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: little vs big endian

Comment: The first way is portable, the second way is not.

Comment: The second way makes a call to a function defined in an library, which comes along with some overhead, new stack frame, state store/restore, even if it is small. The first way shall be much faster, and it is recommended because logical operations do map directly on the CPU routines.

Comment: Both ways store in the same endianess. Even though I am on a big endian machine, the data is store actually in little endian. Both methods store the data in little endian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any advantages or disadvantages to doing it either way?

Yes as the functionality can differ, code should do what is functionally needed.

`cx[0] = x &0xff; cx[1] = (x >> 8) & 0xff;` move the least significant value byte into `cx[0]` and the next most significant byte into `cx[1]`.

`memcpy(cx, (char*)&x, 2);` move the lowest addressed byte of `x` into `cx[0]` and the next addressed byte of `x` into `cx[1]`.

These two approaches are the same functionality when with a certain [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and common `short` size.

What is *best* depends on the larger code and not this narrow snippet.

---

In terms of performance, this falls under [micro optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/99466/94903).  A good compiler can analyze `memcpy()` and emit efficient code without a function call.  A programmer's time is better spent dealing with higher levels of code to improve performance.

---

There is not need for the cast in `memcpy(cx, (char*)&x, 2);`

Be aware that `short` is not always laid out in a certain *endian*.  Uncommonly `short` is not 2 `char`.

`E1 >> 8` leads to "If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined".

Better code would use *unsigned* types and avoid subtle issues.

---

Note there is no `short` to `char` casting here as in the title.

Comment: A better title would have been bitwise operations vs memcpy, but there is a cast in the memcpy ( memcpy(cx, (char*)&x, 2) ). But you are correct about this cast also. It is not necessary. I looked at the gcc code on this, and it is placed into a void * src, so the cast is not needed.

Comment: I also agree with the unsigned data type comment. This would eliminated any issue with the signed bit.